# Is there any way to restrict users from creating "Azure Active Directory" from marketplace?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Azure policy doesn't works on tenant scope and there were no permissions in azure RBAC too for restricting access to create an AAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict users from creating additional tenants using this new handy preview toggle switch setting in Azure AD under

User Settings>Tenant creation>Restrict non-admin users from creating tenants (preview):

[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKy05.png)

This method ensures that only Global Admins can create additional tenants

Answer (score 0):

As it's free to create an azure tenant, it's not something you can restrict access to.
creating an azure tenant has zero affect on a corporations tenant(s).
You can assign RBAC to something you don't own.
What is the reason you'd like to prevent a user from creating their own tenant?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In case there many users under a subscription who create their own tenants and don't delete it, wouldn't all the accumulated tenants create any issue ? since  there are no other ways too to automate deletion of tenants